# Give a new name to axis tick when NA

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar plot with three axis ticks and one of them is NA. Although I can rename the two "non-NA" axis ticks, I can't give a new name to the one named "NA".

How can I do this?

In the example below, "No" can be renamed "test" but "NA" can't be renamed "Unknown":

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

data_plot <- as.data.frame(Titanic) %>%
  add_row(Class = "Crew",
          Sex = "Female",
          Age = "Adult",
          Survived = NA,
          Freq = 20)

ggplot(data_plot, aes(x = factor(Survived),  
                 y = factor(Sex),
                 fill = factor(Class),
                 color = factor(Class))) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("No" = "test", 
                              "NA" = "Unknown"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using fct_explicit_na

```
library(forcats)
data_plot <- as.data.frame(Titanic) %>%
  add_row(Class = "Crew",
          Sex = "Female",
          Age = "Adult",
          Survived = NA,
          Freq = 20)

ggplot(data_plot, aes(x = fct_explicit_na(Survived,na_level = "Unknown"),  
                      y = factor(Sex),
                      fill = factor(Class),
                      color = factor(Class))) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("No" = "test"))
```

[image]